# Norm of the operator induced by the essential bounded function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Consider a measure space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$. Let $\alpha\in L^\infty$. Here $L^\infty$ means $L^\infty(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$. Let $T\colon L^p\to L^p, f\mapsto \alpha\cdot f$ for some fixed $p\in(1,\infty)$. Find the norm $\lVert T\rVert$.
**My thoughts**: I want to prove $\lVert T\rVert =\lVert \alpha\rVert_\infty $ since this is a natural norm and I have proved $\lVert T\rVert \leq\lVert \alpha\rVert_\infty$. To get the reversed inequality, I supposed that $\mu$ is a finite measure and the inequality follows from Chebyshev's inequality (considering the set $E_\varepsilon=\{\omega\in\Omega: |\alpha(\omega)|>\lVert\alpha\rVert_\infty-\varepsilon\}$ and $\chi_{E_\varepsilon}\in L^{p}$).
If $\mu$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure, I think the inequality can be proved similarly: let $A_1\subseteq A_2\subseteq \cdots \subseteq A_n\subseteq \cdots$ be a sequence of sets with finite measure and consider the sets $A_j\cap E_\varepsilon$. Then the monotone convergence theorem works.
**I wonder**:
In which ways can we prove the reversed inequality without assumption on $\mu$, or is there some counterexamples?

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1506434/operator-norm-of-the-multiplication-operator) has discussed the  $\sigma$-finite case.

Comment: If $\mu (A)=\infty$ for every non-empty set $A$ the $L^{p}=\{0\}$ and $T=0$ but $\alpha\|_{\infty}$ is arbitrary.

Comment: @geetha290krm Yes, I proved this using the Chebyshev's inequality. But how does this result work here?

Comment: @geetha290krm thank you, I think I have done.